# How to tell when select2 is not visibly showing the currently selected value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Using Select2 v4.0.3.

When using a "form recovery" addon in Firefox (eg. "Lazarus"), values on a form are all set, however custom controls like Select2 aren't notified of a change. So sometimes there may be a discrepancy between a SELECT's actual selected value and what Select2 is displaying.

So I would like to periodically check all Select2 controls to ensure their visible status is accurate.

I have tried checking like this:

`if (sel.select2("val") != sel.val()) { sel.select2("change"); } // needs an update`

However the values are always the same, indicating the "val" method is not what the select2 control is *visibly* showing, just what it *thinks* it is showing.

What method can I use with Select2 to check if its visible status does not match the actual selected value?

Comment: @ingredient_15939 fiddle it so will get a clear idea.

Comment: sel.select2("val") will return an array of  id/text objects where sel.val() will return a string.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

```
// assuming sel is already defined.
var sel2 = sel.select2("val") 
if(sel2 and sel2.length > ){
    if(sel2[0].id != sel.val()) {
        sel.trigger("change");
    } 
}
else {
   // nothing is selected so trigger change to resync
  sel.trigger("change");
}
```

Where I used similar code this, I already had the sel.on("change... defined so on the trigger I added a second parameter "resync" to tell the registered handler to not do anything. That looked like this:

```
sel.on("change", function(evt, status) {
     if(status != "resync") {
         // rest of the code

     }

});
```

then I trigger it like this

```
sel.trigger("change", "resync");
```

or you can just be lazy and just blindly trigger the event without doing any checking to resync.

```
sel.trigger("change");
```

The select to handlers should do the rest.